# How to handle Number format Exception?

Tags: java, string

My requirement is to check divisibility of the input by 7, for the various test cases and I have written this code but it is throwing me NumberFormat Exception

```
class Solution{
    int isdivisible7(String num){
        // code her
          long i= Long.parseLong(num);
       // to convert string into long 
       if(i%7==0)
       return 1;
       else
       return 0;
    }
}
```

How can I handle the exception and return the result for any (both valid and invalid) input ?

Comment: What is the input? The error happens because whatever `num` is, it is not a number.

Comment: Only pass it something that's a valid number? Are you leaning on a newline? Spaces? It's hard to know what kind of answer you expect.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but why do you return 0 or 1 instead of a more semantically appropriate boolean?

Comment: get the input formats , catch the exception and handle the inputs one by one

Comment: input is string and i have converted it into long and have to check divisibility for 7 if divisible return 1 else 0

Answer (score 3):

If the input `num` is not number, then it will throw `NumberFormatException`, so you just have to catch it. Also, function names should be in camel case. And finally, it's better to make the function return `boolean` rather then `int` of values 0 and 1.

```
boolean isDivisibleBy7(String num){
    try {
        long i = Long.parseLong(num);
        return i % 7 == 0;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // print some error message if you want
        System.out.println("You haven't passed number");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but missing return statement is showing  what else i have to do

Comment: Check my answer now.

Comment: 46825380952940387566759192377741543....... for this test case it is giving me the wrong output

Comment: @KashishBansal that's because it is way too big for `long`, as its max value is `2^63-1 = 9,22 * 10^18`

Comment: how to solve this issue?

Comment: You have to use `BigInteger`